# Legend not showing when plotting multiple seaborn plots

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I typically don't have problems with matplotlib legend, but this is the first time I am using it with multiple seaborn plots, and the following does not work.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
a =sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY1', data=data)
b = sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY2', data=data)
c = sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY3', data=data)
fig.legend(handles=[a, b, c],labels=['First','Second','Third'])
fig.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`seaborn.regplot` returns an axes. You cannot create a legend proxy handle from an axes. However this is not even necessary. Remove the `handles` from the legend and it should give the desired plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data=pd.DataFrame({"VarX" : np.arange(10), 
                   'VarY1': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY2': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY3': np.random.rand(10)})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY1', data=data)
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY2', data=data)
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY3', data=data)
fig.legend(labels=['First','Second','Third'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does not work for me: it gives "TypeError: legend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'handles'". I am using matplotlib v2.0.2

Comment: Yes, `fig.legend()` is only possible from 2.1 on. But you can call the legend on the axes, because all plots are part of that axes, `ax.legend()`.